# How can I implement a dbus data in go that has signature of yya(yuayu)?

Tags: go

I am working on implementing a dbus client using godbus. The client is supposed to call a method in the server that expects data in the format "yya(yuayu)". I initially thought that I can get the A9yuayu) part implemented using struct but found out that this is invalid because godbus does not support user-defined data types. I tried creating this data using interface as shown below

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/godbus/dbus/v5"
)

func main() {

    var signal1 = []interface{}{uint8(0), uint32(0), [2]uint8{0, 0}, uint32(0)}

    var signal = []interface{}{uint8(0), uint8(0), []interface{}{uint8(0), uint32(0), [2]uint8{0, 0}, uint32(0)}}

    fmt.Println(dbus.SignatureOf(signal1...))
    fmt.Println(dbus.SignatureOf(signal...))

}
```

Signature of signal1 came back as "yyav"

Even though I can get the signature of signal as "yuayu", I am not able to create data that would conform to "yya(yuayu)". I am looking for suggestions/guidance that will help me address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by making the capitalizing the first character of elements of the struct, which allowed these to be accessible to dbus.SignatureOf() method

package main

import (
"fmt"

```
"github.com/godbus/dbus/v5"
```

)

type testOut struct {
ID       uint8
Type     uint32
Address  [2]uint8
Response uint32
}

func main() {

```
signal := make([]testOut, 0)

fmt.Println(dbus.SignatureOf(signal))

var i int

for i = 0; i < 2; i++ {

    signal = append(signal, testOut{ID: uint8(i), Type: uint32(i + 1), 
           Address: [2]uint8{uint8(i + 2)}, Response: uint32(i + 10)})

}

fmt.Println(signal)
fmt.Println(dbus.SignatureOf(signal))
```

}